# Normalizing Validation error types

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to find the most convenient way to normalize the error types in a for-comprehension on scalaz.Validations in one "upper" layer that calls into methods returning Validations with differing error types on "lower" layers. Naturally there needs to be defined a mapping for each lower-level error type to an upper-layer error type but I cannot seem to get around providing explicit type-hints within the for comprehensions for my implicits to be picked up. I'd like to leave each line of the for-comprehension clean of explicit conversion of the error type (e.g. through .fail.map(...).validation. I tried an approach with an IsUpperError type-trait and an implicit conversion as follows:

```
package errorhandling

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

class LowerServiceA {
  def doStuff(): Validation[LowerServiceAError, Int] = Success(1)
}
sealed trait LowerServiceAError
// ... more specific error types

class LowerServiceB {
  def doStuff(): Validation[LowerServiceBError, Int] = Success(1)
}
sealed trait LowerServiceBError
// ... more specific error types

class LowerServiceC {
  def doStuff(): Validation[LowerServiceCError, Int] = Success(1)
}
sealed trait LowerServiceCError
// ... more specific error types

sealed trait UpperError {}
// ... more specific error types
trait IsUpperError[E] {
  def apply(e: E): UpperError
}
object IsUpperError {
  implicit val lowerServiceAErrorIsUpperError: IsUpperError[LowerServiceAError] = new IsUpperError[LowerServiceAError] {
    def apply(err: LowerServiceAError) = new UpperError {}
  }

  implicit val lowerServiceBErrorIsUpperError: IsUpperError[LowerServiceBError] = new IsUpperError[LowerServiceBError] {
    def apply(err: LowerServiceBError) = new UpperError {}
  }

  implicit val lowerServiceCErrorIsUpperError: IsUpperError[LowerServiceCError] = new IsUpperError[LowerServiceCError] {
    def apply(err: LowerServiceCError) = new UpperError {}
  }
}

object UpperError {
  implicit def upperError[E: IsUpperError, A](v: Validation[E, A]): Validation[UpperError, A] =
    v.fail.map(e => implicitly[IsUpperError[E]].apply(e)).validation
}

class UpperService(serviceA: LowerServiceA, serviceB: LowerServiceB, serviceC: LowerServiceC) {
  def doStuff(): Validation[UpperError, Int] = {
    for {
      // I'd like to avoid the repeated type-hints or .fail.map(...).validation here
      a <- serviceA.doStuff() // : Validation[UpperError, Int]
      b <- serviceB.doStuff() // : Validation[UpperError, Int]
      c <- serviceC.doStuff()
    } yield a + b + c
  }
}
```

The compiler error (2.9.2) without the type-hints:

```
ErrorHandling.scala:56: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type errorhandling.IsUpperError[java.lang.Object]
  b <- serviceB.doStuff() //: Validation[UpperError, Int]
    ^
```

one error found

I'd also appreciate guidance if the desire to do this kind of thing hints at a problem in how I approach this kind of error-handling.